# Compiling C-dll for Python OR SWIG-module creation, how to continue?

Tags: python, c, dll, swig

I reference this file "**kbdext.c**" and its headerfile listed on http://www.docdroppers.org/wiki/index.php?title=Writing_Keyloggers (the listings are at the bottom).

I've been trying to **compile** this into a **dll** for use in **Python or Visual Basic**, but have not succeeded. I'm not familiar with C or **GCC** to sort out the problems or do the dll compile correctly. (I also get an error about *snprintf* not being declared when doing a regular compile of all the files).

**What** are the steps I should do to make all functions available for other languages and external apps?

Or is it perhaps easier to use **SWIG** and make a python module, instead of compiling a DLL?

Comment: try [`pyHook`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

I've succeeded in compiling the dll with GCC, and am able to import its functions in C. I have yet to test the import in VB and Python but can't see why it would pose problems.